# graphql-client ruby mutation example

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to ruby on rails. Trying to implement a class that interacts with a GraphQL server. I was able to successfully execute a mutation with hardcoded values but I want to pass dynamic values to the query where I am facing challenges.

The following query works fine...

```
MutationQuery = GraphqlClient.parse <<-'GRAPHQL'
                mutation{
                  createEmployee(input:{email:"XXX",familyName:"xxxx",givenName:"xxx"}){id}
                }
           GRAPHQL
```

When running with

```
variables = {<some values not required>}
result = GraphqlClient.query(MutationQuery, variables: variables)
```

However, I have a @employee object from where I need to pick the values for this query. Appreciate any leads on this.